# File path in Layer Panel in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, panel, disable

How can I disable file path balloon in Layer panel? When I pass the cursor in any object in Layer panel I see an annoying long text showing the file path. I would like to disable it.

[image: example of layer panel]

Comment: Seems to be already answered in https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/373998/67477